# Displaying JFrames inside JSplitPane Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jsplitpane

I'm making GUI using `JSplitPane` and I want to display a `JFrame` in the left side of the `JSplitPane` and another `JFrame` inside the right side of a `JSplitPane`.
The name of the other `JFrame` is `Minimize.java` and `Diagram.java`. My problem is how can i call these and display it in the left and right side of the `JSplitPane`? An update for this post, I converted my JFrame to a JPanel and successful displayed but the problem now is it didn't perform the function/method.

Here's my code for the Main Form.

```
        public LogicGates()
        {
            Minimize mi = new Minimize();

             //mi.setVisible(true);
            JLabel iExp = new JLabel("Inputted Expression: ");
            p.add(iExp);
            j1= new JLabel("");
            j1.setVisible(false);
            p.add(j1);


            JScrollPane aaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(aa);

//here is my problem,when i run the code it displays the label and jcombobox but didn't perform the function
            gatessplit = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, mi, aaScrollPane);
            gatessplit.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            gatessplit.setDividerLocation(300);

            //Provide minimum sizes for the two components in the split pane.
            Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(150, 80);
            //frame.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
            aaScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);

            //Provide a preferred size for the split pane.
            gatessplit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 500));


        }
```

Comment: Why a JFrame? Aren't those top-level components? Wouldn't a panel be more appropriate?

Comment: Sir I tried to convert it to a Jpanel but there are some components that does not support so I used Jframe. Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: *"Jpanel but there are some components that does not support"* Perhaps you need a `JDesktopPane` with `JInternalFrame` instances.

Comment: Is it possible that i can insert the internal frame inside the splitpane Sir?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. A JFrame must sit by itself. Period. If "there are some components that does not support..." then you're fixing the wrong thing. Tell us what components you mean, and then use JPanels.

Comment: Please start comments to me with @Andrew so I get notified.  A `JInternalFrame` is added to a `JDesktopPane`.  The desktop pane can be added to anything that will accept a `Container`.  I suggested internal frames because they were more like a frame, but note that since you can add multiple internal frames to 1 desktop page, the split pane does not make much sense any longer.  Just have 1 desktop pane instead, with any number of internal frames.  (And please don't call me 'Sir'.  plan 'Andrew' is fine.)

Comment: @Andrew Ihave an update on my code, I have converted it to a JPanel but it didn't perform the function,just display.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (rather than uncompilable code snippets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use `JPanels` here combined with a `Layout Manager` on the `JFrame`?

This will allow you to create a `JFrame`, then add a layout to it comprising of two sections on the left and right. You can then add a `JPanel` to the left and right and add components to each `JPanel`.

**JPanel tutorial**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html

**Layout tutorial**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: 3 files namely Minimize.java,LogicGates.java,Diagram.java all of them extends JFrame. I use JFrame coz some components doesnt support in JPanel.

Comment: @Alvin: Are the JFrame classes classes that you've created? If so, re-write them to produce JPanels, not JFrames.

Comment: @AlvinPulido: what components do you mean that aren't supported in JPanel?